# UIScrollView: addSubview does not add item

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I spent a few hours, trying to solve my problem, but I can't find solution myself.
I have some code, adding UIView to my scrollView:

```
- (void) loadSpareparts:(VitoParts*) parts{
    data = [VitoServer fetchPartList:parts];

    int itemHeight = 100;
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, (data.count * itemHeight))];

    NSLog(@"Item count: %d", data.count);

    for (int i=0; i<data.count; i++) {
        VitoPart *sparepart = [data objectAtIndex:i];
        VIOnePart *partView = [[VIOnePart alloc] init];

        [partView setFrame:CGRectMake (0, (i * itemHeight), scrollView.frame.size.width, itemHeight)];

        [partView setData:sparepart];
        [scrollView addSubview:partView];
        //        [self.view addSubview:partView];
    }

    NSLog(@"In scrollView: %d", scrollView.subviews.count);
}
```

But it is not working. My last log message tells, what 0 items in `scrollView`.
If I add `partView` to `self.view`, it is working OK.
IBOutlet also is connected to ScrollView in XIB-editor.

Where I should try to find solution?

Thanks.

Comment: are adding scrollView to self.view at some point?

Comment: scrollView placed in interface editor and connected by outled to scrollView variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling this method before or after `-(void)viewDidLoad`? If before, the view will not have loaded hence `scrollView` will be nil.

Comment: Thanks :) It is difficult to make programs after NY :)

Comment: This answer help me. Could you kindly tell me why should I load in viewDidLoad?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad